# How to implement rotor with auto-text for my custom input method in VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, voiceover, rotor

I develop a input method. I want to let the blind to use it easily. I know screen reader that is installed in IOS called VoiceOver. Blinds can you rotor item "auto-text" to make selection of candidate list item. But I don't know how to do. How should I do for this case?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but it looks like you'd be interested in learning about `UIAccessibility`. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/index.html

Comment: Are you asking if you can add a custom rotor item? If so, are you trying to do it everywhere in your app or only when a certain element has focus?

Answer (score 0):

Since **iOS 10**, adding a new rotor option is possible thanks to the `UIAccessibilityCustomRotor` whose creation is based on 2 elements :

1. `UIAccessibilityCustomRotorSearchPredicate` : defines the logic according to
   the flick type on the screen.
2. `UIAccessibilityCustomRotorItemResult` : ensued element from the logic above.

Code snippets *(ObjC, swift)* and illustrations are [provided](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-rotor) if you need further explanations for your implementation.